# How can I import uploadcare into a react.js project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uploadcare

How can I import uploadcare into a react.js project?

My imports section looks like this

```
    // main imports
    import React from 'react';
    import {render} from 'react-dom';
    import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
    import jQuery from '../scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'
    import uploadcare from '../lib/uploadcare.min.js'
```

And then I would like to use uploadcare like this (via the javascript API):

```
onAddPhotosClick: function() {
    console.log("++ add photos");
    uploadcare.openDialog(null, {
        publicKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        imagesOnly: true,
        tabs: "file url facebook gdrive dropbox instagram evernote flickr skydrive"
    });
},
```

My code reaches the openDialog line, and then throws this error:

```
:8081/static/react_build/bundle.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: _uploadcareMin2.default.openDialog is not a function
```

Earlier, during the page load, my console logs:

```
Global public key not set. Uploads may not work!
Add this to the <head> tag to set your key:

<script>
UPLOADCARE_PUBLIC_KEY = 'your_public_key';
</script>
:8081/static/react_build/bundle.js:85 ++ add photos
```

The fact that I get this brown warning message above (which I am ok with because I am hoping to set
the public key directly through the javascript API) makes me think that uploadcare.js file has
been included properly, but the uploadCareMin2 error makes me think that I am not importing it quite correctly.

TL;DR; How can I import the uploadcare Javascript API into a react.js project?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please note what we've added CommonJS compatibility only in [2.8.0 version](https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-widget/blob/master/HISTORY.markdown#280-14032016). I'm not sure how React works, but we populate `module.exports` if it is present (not `window.uploadcare`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `uploadcare` is but try

```
import '../lib/uploadcare.min.js'
```

It looks like you're importing the file directly meaning you would have to hope the author exported the file as `export default` in order to import it the way you showed. It's likely they just stick it in global space.

If not, it's also possible they exported a named value so try:

```
import { uploadcare } from '../lib/uploadcare.min.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now also use npm install as documented on [uploadcare's website](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/widget/):

```
NPM
npm install uploadcare-widget

ES6 usage way:
import uploadcare from 'uploadcare-widget';

CommonJS usage way:
var uploadcare = require('uploadcare-widget);
```